# Undefined variable error when using defined variable in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

I'm making a website where i login, press a button and then some information is loaded from a database. The code works fine expect for one thing which is: I get this error:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: error in <b>/character-load.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />
```

But the variable is defined here:

```
if ($user["banned"] == 1){ 
$error = 1;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($character) == 0){ 
$error = 1;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($username) == 0){ 
$error = 1;
}
if (empty($charid)){ 
$error = 1;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this? I dont understand why it says that the variable error is undefined? I can add more information on request as i don't really know what more to add.

Comment: `$error` is only defined inside the `conditional` scope.
Define it outside it to supress the notice.

Comment: I think you have to define it before if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$error = 0;
if ($user["banned"] == 1){ 
  $error = 1;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($character) == 0){ 
  $error = 1;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($username) == 0){ 
  $error = 1;
}
if (empty($charid)){ 
  $error = 1;
}
```

and add check at the time of use.

Comment: Thanks, that did work. For what reason do i have to type `$error = 0;` first?

Comment: See Erik's answer for the explanation

Comment: if none of the condition passes then there would be no variables named `$error`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is only defined if one of these 4 situations occurs. In a situation where none of this occurs, it won't exist.

Easiest fix is to define it as 0 at the top of the block.

Remember; in PHP a variable is only defined if one of the assignment lines is actually executed. Simply being inside the file but being skipped over doesn't count.